# Preg_match: How to read the point seperated Digits (from 1 up to 3 digits) (money value) from a string?

Tags: php, regex

For example:

```
30€
30,00€
1.450€
798.000.000,00€
12.567.789.985,00€
```

How do i convert them to the integer values?

I can not use intval(), because it may occure different number before the actual value in the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - Strip non numeric and remove cents if any](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676065/regex-strip-non-numeric-and-remove-cents-if-any)

Answer (score 1):

Are you always ending with `€`?

If so, try this:

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', preg_replace('/.*?([\d\.,]+)€.*/', '$1', $i));
```

This will search any string with any characters before or after the numeric value, and return just the number (no commas, periods, or euro sign).

Comment: Oh, and if anyone wants to copy-and-paste a working copy: http://pastebin.com/TmULJamb

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove the $ sign

```
$num = substr("30€", 0, -1);
```

then remove spaces and '.' or ',' with str_replace

```
$num = str_replace( '.', '', $num );
$num = str_replace( ',', '', $num );
```

that should be an integer.Try it!
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regexp

```
$str='798.000.000,00€';

$res = strtr($str,array("." => "", "€" => "","," => "."));

var_dump(intval($res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what you want to do with the digits after the decimal point. Do you want to ignore them or preserve them. I think a float would be more appropiate. If so replace dots(just used for grouping) the money symbol and replace the "," with proper decimal point and convert value to float.
There's also a nice parse function [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Answer (score 0):

All your numbers have a common pattern, the regex should match that pattern to extract the numbers. Then you can convert the found numbers into integer values:

```
$str = '30€
30,00€
1.450€
798.000.000,00€
12.567.789.985,00€';

$pattern = '~[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*~';

$r = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

$intValues = array_map(function($v) {return (int) str_replace('.', '', $v);}, $matches[0]);

print_r($intValues);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 1450
    [3] => 798000000
    [4] => 2147483647
)
```